# Java Jpanel print empty page

Tags: java, printing, jpanel

```
private void cmdprintActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

         PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setJobName("Outside Processing System");

                job.setPrintable (new Printable() {

                @Override
                public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){

                if (pageNum > 0){
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }

                OPSPrintPanel panel = new OPSPrintPanel();
                Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D)pg;
                g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
                panel.paint(pg);
                return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;

                }

                });
                boolean ok = job.printDialog();
                if (ok) {
                try {

                job.print();

                } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                }

                }   


          }
```

I'm trying to print a panel and the codes seems okay but when I click print and view it to pdf its only a blank page. I tried so many codes that can print panel but it doesn't print. Even I reinstall my NetBeans and install an updated jdk it won't work.

[Blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCHNJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't dispose object **g2** and use **try catch** block when you print as pdf. First you have to print the image as it is and then try to translate it.

Try this, i hope it would works.

```
        OPSPrintPanel panel = new OPSPrintPanel();   
        //print the panel to pdf
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\test.pdf"));
            document.open();
    // PdfContentByte is an object containing the user positioned text and 
     // graphic contents of a page. It knows how to apply the proper font encoding.
            PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
            PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(500, 500);
            Graphics2D g2 = template.createGraphics(500, 500);
        // First print the panel as it is and then try to translate it by removing comments
       // g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            panel.print(g2);
            g2.dispose();
      // Adds a template to this content.
            contentByte.addTemplate(template, 30, 300);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(document.isOpen())
        {
                document.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: my goal is to print it on printer, I'm using a pdf to view if the code works. My code works if I call my MainFrame but when I want to call a JPanel or other panel, frame the result is blank. The Jpanel that I want to print is consist of labels and a jtable.